# play 2.3 sbt-concat not working in prod

Tags: playframework-2.3, sbt-web, sbt-concat

I want to use this plugin

> addSbtPlugin("net.ground5hark.sbt" % "sbt-concat" % "0.1.8")

To concatenate my assets.

I have 3 groups :

```
Concat.groups := Seq(
  "concat_main.css" -> group(Seq(
    "stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css",
    "stylesheets/font-awesome.css",
    "stylesheets/totem/sidebar/component.css",
    "stylesheets/main.min.css"
  )),
  "concat_main.js" -> group(Seq(
    "javascripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js",
    "javascripts/bootstrap.min.js",
    "javascripts/totemPage/sidebar/modernizr.custom.js",
    "javascripts/totemPage/respond.min.js",
    "javascripts/totemPage/html5shiv.js",
    "javascripts/totemPage/sidebar/classie.js",
    "javascripts/main.js"
  )),
  "concat_noel.js" -> group(Seq(
    "javascripts/totemPage/ouibounce-modal.js",
    "javascripts/ouibounce_modal.js",
    "javascripts/homePage.js",
    "javascripts/totemPage/jquery.cookie.js",
    "javascripts/embed.js"
  ))
)

Concat.parentDir := "public/main/javascripts"

pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(concat, uglify, digest, gzip)
```

Files are generated in dev, I can access

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/concat_main.css")">
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/concat_main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But with `activator start` I have a 404.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the [sbt-web documentation](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web) you can read that:

> If you have some need for the assets produced by the pipelineStages in
>   your development environment (during play run), then you can scope the
>   pipelineStages to the Assets config.
>
> pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(myPipelineTask)

And this is what you have done which is setting the `pipelineStages` key scoped to the **Assets configuration**. However, this works only for the development mode. In order to run the pipeline in the production mode you have to set the `pipelineStages` key scoped to the **Global configuration**. In your case this will look like this:

```
pipelineStages := Seq(concat, uglify, digest, gzip)
```

Comment: I'm sure some will disagree, but that's not really intuitive. Uses of scoping throughout SBT projects seems (to me at least) to be idiosyncratic.